# ArcGIS Online: numeric field is recognized as string

Tags: arcgis-online

**Context**
I am trying to prepare a dashboard using ArcGIS Online only (ie I can't use ArcGIS Pro/Desktop because I use Linux).

**The problem**
I uploaded a CVS file to have my initial features layer. The problem is one column that is supposed to be numeric (I double-checked potential encoding issues) but it is recognized by ArcGIS online as string. And I don't find any way to change that (from within ArcGIS Online).
The column has around 25k rows. Less than 20% of them are numbers (float, 2 decimal digits), while the rest are empty cells.

**What I tried**

- First, I confirmed using my spreadsheet programs that the column is
  effectively numeric.
- I also confirmed that everything is OK using a plain-text editor.
- I tried formatting the whole column as Numeric with 2 decimal digits before exporting the file as CSV.
- I tried sorting the rows so the numeric values are on top (in case ArcGIS uses the first rows to decide the data type).
- In ArcGIS Online, I created an expression using the absolute value of this column, hoping that the empty cells would be numeric. Didn't work
- From my spreadsheet program, I used NaN values instead of empty cells.

Nothing worked until now...
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if ArcGIS Online made use of these but you may try to use a .csvt along your .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hornbydd said, it was my own making... I always export CVS with quoted fields for strings. I think this is the most sensible way to let the applications know that whatever is between quotes is a string, and the rest is either numeric or datetime. I have always done it like that and never had any problems... but it turns out ArcGIS Online does have a problem with that.

So, I removed the quotes and exported again, and now the column is recognized as a numeric field as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this is a problem of your own making, CSV is a poor format, for anything but the most basic data. I avoid it like the plague for the very reason your are experiencing, it does not enforce data format. It even says that in the help file [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/csv-gpx.htm#GUID-4EDCE12E-285E-41D0-A3B8-1BAB4B111922).

You say you have linux, install [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), then read up on the various help out there on the internet and turn your CSV into a proper spatial dataset, such as zipped up [shapefile](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm). A shapefile file will enforce correct field types. You will then have confidence in your hosted feature layer being correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks. I added an update. Creating a shapefile for just a small table seemed an overkill to me (especially because I will need to update it frequently, and I don't want to create the ZIP file everytime only to update a typo or things like that). In the end I found the problem and will still use CSV for this situations. For more 'serious' dataset I will follow your advice though.